# Add a border/shadow effect to UIView

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I've managed to draw a speech bubble with following code:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let rounding:CGFloat = rect.width * 0.01

    //Draw the main frame
    let bubbleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height * 6 / 7)

    let bubblePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bubbleFrame,
                                  byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners,
                                  cornerRadii: CGSize(width: rounding, height: rounding))

    //Color the bubbleFrame
    color.setStroke()
    color.setFill()
    bubblePath.stroke()
    bubblePath.fill()

    //Add the point
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //Start the line
    context!.beginPath()
    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: bubbleFrame.minX + bubbleFrame.width * 1/2 - 8, y: bubbleFrame.maxY))

    //Draw a rounded point
    context?.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 1/2 + 4, y: rect.maxY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x:bubbleFrame.maxX , y:  bubbleFrame.minY), radius: 0)

    //Close the line
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bubbleFrame.minX + bubbleFrame.width * 1/2 + 16, y: bubbleFrame.maxY))

    context!.closePath()

    //fill the color
    context?.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context?.fillPath()

   context?.saveGState()
    context?.setShadow(offset:CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), blur: 2, color: UIColor.gray.cgColor)
    UIColor.gray.setStroke()
    bubblePath.lineWidth = 0.5
    bubblePath.stroke()
    context?.restoreGState()

}
```

At the moment, it looks like this:
[image]

I seem to be having trouble adding a shadow effect to the speech bubble. I want the point at the bottom to have the shadow effect, no just the rectangle above.  Also, the shadow/border at the top is too thick. This is the end result I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Not answering the question at all, but doing: `guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }` will clean up the code by giving you a non-Optional, prevent nil crashes, and making it no longer look like context is having an argument with itself: context? context! context...

Comment: @BaseZen Yeah good point, i'll fix that

Comment: @luke you are trying to make a custom callout? can i post a way to make a custom callout like you need?